# proof of associative-ring

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to check if the structure is ring
define the structure in this way:
$R$={${\frac{m}{2n+1},+,*} $} $n,m\in \mathbb Z$
i want to prove associativity in relation to +
$(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$
$(a+b)+c=a/(2c+1)(2b+1)$
$a+(b+c)=a(2c+1)/2b$
i'm missing something here or the group just does not associative?

Answer (score 1):

You need to show

$$\dfrac{a}{2b+1} + \left(\dfrac{c}{2d+1}+\dfrac{e}{2f+1}\right) = \left(\dfrac{a}{2b+1} + \dfrac{c}{2d+1}\right)+\dfrac{e}{2f+1}$$

If you know $\mathbb Q$ is a ring, then you wouldn't need to tediously show this, though.